# SQL - How can I select a record from duplicate records where the latest date in the date column is more than 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a query that selects any computer name from a table where it meets the condition that it has not been scanned in 30 days. In theory SYSDATE - 30 is ideal, however the challenge here is that there can be duplicate entries for each system.

So in the below query, I am selecting computers from a table where the report week is this week and the last scan was more than 30 days ago. Because there is more than one entry for this system this week it returns systems that have had a scan within the 30 days. As one record says it has scanned this week but another says it has not.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  computer_name
FROM
  scan_table st
WHERE
  report_week >= SYSDATE - 7
AND
  st.last_scan_date < SYSDATE - 30
```

it returns x system even though x system scanned yesterday because a duplicate record says the last time that x system scanned was in February.

yes the obvious answer is to purge the duplicates from the DB but this is not an option so I need a way to filter based on the latest date available within the last_scan_date column.

I tried using MAX(st.last_scan_date) however that's not allowed to be used in a WHERE clause
I saw results where it's suggested to use a SELECT Sub Query however, that just brings this issue back up. Unless I'm using the subquery incorrectly

I am using ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you target the latest values of `report_week` and `last_scan_date` you can use aggregation and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT computer_name
FROM scan_table 
GROUP BY computer_name
HAVING MAX(report_week) >= SYSDATE - 7 AND MAX(last_scan_date) < SYSDATE - 30;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply forpas and I did try something similar to this earlier, however when attempting to use MAX in HAVING it returns the error 'not a GROUP BY expression', presumably due to it being Oracle SQL and not just SQL

Comment: @Neodreadlord if you get the error `'not a GROUP BY expression'` then you did not use my query as it is, because I select `computer_name` and group by `computer_name`, so the select list is the same as the group by list.

Comment: that's exactly what I did. SELECT computer_name and Group By computer_name

Comment: @Neodreadlord What about the HAVING clause.  My query runs without errors: https://dbfiddle.uk/U9sbScha

Comment: @Neodreadlord can you reproduce the error that you get in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k26Sg7fD)?

Comment: Ok no now I get a totally different error re using a number where it expected a date but I see where I made the mistake vs what you suggested. I still had it in the where clause and not in the HAVING only clause. I'm going to attempt this again and let you know. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Thanks so much Forpas. This worked. I removed all where clauses as originally my query was more in depth than what I posted. I got it to work with your suggestion and then gradually reimplemented the additional WHERE clauses. It's returned back 53 unique instances which I'm going through to validate manually but being that it's given me results and a lesser number than I had prior to your suggestion I'm quietly hopeful that this is a final solution. I'll update further if it isn't

Comment: Unfortunately after going through it manually, this is showing me results that have a completed scans in the last couple of days. So using the HAVING is not excluding them from the list. Would the additional where clauses be over-riding this? they're not on the same fields, so I would have thought they'd only reduce the list not add to it.

Comment: @Neodreadlord there is no way that the condition `MAX(last_scan_date) < SYSDATE - 30` would return `computer_name`s  with `last_scan_date` in *the last couple of days*. Obviously you made other changes to the query for which I can't help you.

Comment: I will attempt to create a more accurate example on fiddle tomorrow to show you what's happening. Honestly the additions I've made should not in my mind logically upset anything in the HAVING clause but maybe I'm missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists, to filter out previous scans of the same computer.

```sql
SELECT 
    computer_name,
    last_scan_date
FROM
    scan_table st
WHERE
    report_week >= SYSDATE - 7
    AND st.last_scan_date < SYSDATE - 30
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        select
            1
        from
            scan_table st2
        where
            st.computer_name = st2.computer_name
            and st2.last_scan_date > st.last_scan_date
    )
```

Additionally, you gain chance to see actual last scan date.

Comment: Thanks Markalex for your answer. However, attempting the above, this just removes any of those that have a duplicate rather than showing me ones that are still falling into the category of those that don't have a scan in more than 30 days. So if they have a duplicate record at all, they aren't in the list, even if all the scan dates are outside the 30 days. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @Neodreadlord, this shouldn't happen: `EXISTS` clause eliminates all older scans, `st.last_scan_date < SYSDATE - 30` shows form them only those where scan happen more than a month ago.

Comment: @Neodreadlord, could you check results with only `EXISTS` in your query? (without `report_week >= SYSDATE - 7
    AND st.last_scan_date < SYSDATE - 30`)

Comment: This returns the same thing, it removes everything other than records that don't have a duplicate. I'm not understanding why. If I read what you suggested correctly, I changed it to 
'''
AND EXISTS(
SELECT
  1
FROM
  scan_table st2
WHERE
  st.computer_name = st2.computer_name
  AND st2.last_scan_date > st.last_scan_date
) '''

?

Comment: @Neodreadlord, very strange. See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QBJe8Jz9), it work like it should, or am i missing something?

Comment: No that's exactly as I have it but on my end it returns only entries without duplicates. It's very strange

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the meaning of "week" for you, you may try one of these:

```
select computer_name, max(last_scan_date) as last_scan_date from scan_table st 
where to_char(last_scan_date,'W') = to_char(SYSDATE ,'W')
and not exists(
  select 1 from scan_table st1 
  where st.computer_name = st1.computer_name
  and st1.last_scan_date <= sysdate - 30 
  and to_char(st1.last_scan_date,'W') <> to_char(st.last_scan_date,'W')
)
group by computer_name
;

select computer_name, max(last_scan_date) as last_scan_date from scan_table st 
where last_scan_date >= SYSDATE-7
and not exists(
  select 1 from scan_table st1 
  where st.computer_name = st1.computer_name
  and st1.last_scan_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 7 AND SYSDATE - 30 
)
group by computer_name
;
```